# missing Schema.contentsHaveChangedSince in v1.18

Tags: apache-calcite

According the document "JSON/YAML models", "However, it also leads to the problem of cache staleness. A particular schema implementation can override the Schema.contentsHaveChangedSince method to tell Calcite when it should consider its cache to be out of date."
But I can't find the method in calcite v1.18, how can I implement the function?